# Python- Looping through pandas Groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is a sample row that I have in my dataframe:

```
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "3652b5d7-55b8-4bee-82b6-ab32d5543352",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "true"
}
```

I do groupby by 'sessionId', which will give me a group like this:

```
Row 1:
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "usecaseId1",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "false"
},
 Row 2:
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "usecaseId1",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "false"
},
Row 3:
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "usecaseId2",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "true"
},
Row 4:
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "usecaseId1",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "false"
},
Row 5:
{
"sessionId" : "454ec8b8-7f00-40b2-901c-724c5d9f5a91",
"useCaseId" : "usecaseId1",
"timestamp" : "1559403699899",
"endFlow" : "true"
}
```

Taking the above group as example, what I want to achieve here is, after grouping the dataframe by 'sessionId', I want to loop through consecutive rows with same 'useCaseId'(So from, the above group, there will be three sets of consecutive rows through which I want to loop,
**Row1-Row2,Row3,Row4-Row5**)

And from each of the above consecutive sets of rows(**Row1-Row2,Row3,Row4-Row5 (Where each set has same useCaseId)**,
 **I want to find the number of sets who's rows endflow value in only false**.

So, from the above given example of group,the expected outcome is as follows:
**1(Since, Row1-Row2 with same useCaseId 'usecaseId1' has endflow only 'false', while 'Row3' and 'Row4-Row5' has endflow 'true')**

How can I achieve this?
**Updates:**

1. df.head():

   ```
   sessionId   useCaseId      timestamp endFlow
   0  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899   false
   1  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899   false
   2  sessionId1  useCaseId2  1559403699899    true
   3  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899   false
   4  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899    true
   ```
2. What I tried:
   I have tried grouping the dataframe by 'sessionId' and 'usecaseId',but that won't work because it will group the dataframe uniquely with 'usecaseId' which is not what I wanted, I want to loop through consecutive rows after grouping by 'sessionId' with same 'usecaseId', and then count the consecutive rows with same 'useCaseId' having 'endFlow' only as 'false'.
3. Expected output:
   After grouping by 'sessionId', I want to count the number of consecutive rows with same 'useCaseId' having 'endFlow' only as 'false'
   **from the above given example of group,the expected outcome is as follows: 
   1(Since, Row1-Row2 with same useCaseId 'usecaseId1' has endflow only 'false', while 'Row3' and 'Row4-Row5' has endflow 'true')**

Comment: please edit your post to include the following info: 1) `df.head()` -- please [edit] your question with some of this data, it is a lot easier to copy-paste. 2) include any code you've run and why it did not work, and 3) please add your expected output for the given data sample.

Comment: @cs95 I have updated my question, can you please have a look? :)
This is so important to me man, I really need your help here...

Comment: I think you are looking for `(~(df['endFlow'] == "true").groupby([df['sessionId'], df['useCaseId'].ne(df['useCaseId'].shift()).cumsum()]).max()).sum()`

Comment: @cs95, That worked! Below answer by Andy also worked. 
 However, I have another requirement now, where I have to do this action and group only for a list of 'useCaseId's. How can I achieve this? I mean, to say, I dont want to group the above dataframe with all the useCaseIds thats present in 'useCaseId' column, but I want to group it against a list of useCaseId's that I have, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this: (*I assume `df.endFlow` contains string of `'true'` and `'false'`. If it contains boolean `True` and `False`, you just take out the `replace` command*.)

```
df.endFlow.replace({'true': True, 'false': False}).groupby([df.sessionId, df.useCaseId.ne(df.useCaseId.shift()).cumsum()]).sum().eq(False).sum()

Out[1258]: 1
```

Now, I change your sample to include 2 groups satisfying condition, it also reports count correctly as follows:

```
df1:
    sessionId   useCaseId      timestamp  endFlow
0  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899    false
1  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899    false
2  sessionId1  useCaseId2  1559403699899     true
3  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899    false
4  sessionId1  useCaseId1  1559403699899    false

df1.endFlow.replace({'true': True, 'false': False}).groupby([df1.sessionId, df1.useCaseId.ne(df1.useCaseId.shift()).cumsum()]).sum().eq(False).sum()

Out[1264]: 2
```

Note: I understand from your description that a group with a single row is also consider as consecutive-row group. Therefore, the count will include it if its `endFlow` is `False`

Comment: Brilliant! That worked! However, I have another requirement now, where I have to do this action and group only for a list of 'useCaseId's. How can I achieve this? I mean, to say, I dont want to group the above dataframe with all the useCaseIds thats present in 'useCaseId' column, but I want to group it against a list of useCaseId's that I have, is it possible?

Comment: @TonyMathew: It is possible. However, please ask a new question and provide detail information about new requirements, input, and desired ouput as you did in this question. You may also include a link back to this question. Sample and desired ouput are worth more than thousand words. As in this question, without your updated of `df.head()`, I am kind of lost.